# How To Run Laravel Websockets On Production

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I have hosted my project on hostinger shared hosting. but i am not able start websocket server.
So how I can start websocket server.
When call websockets:serve via artisan call i face to timeout.
I  tired to start webstocket like this.

sample code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
Artisan::call('websockets:serve');
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://medium.com/@saineshmamgain/setting-up-laravel-websockets-on-production-server-using-nginx-proxy-with-letsencrypt-ssl-f22f67d352e basically you will need supervisor and nginx reverse proxy